# Tips for developing on remote (live) server

Tags: php, server, backup

I am just learning PHP because I paid someone to develop a fairly large data mining site which uses two dedicated servers.  They have abandoned the project, now I have the working version on my servers which can't be edited locally due to many cron jobs, two dedicated servers and several api's.

What are the best practices for working on a live server?  What is the correct way to backup on the fly?  Any software that automates this?

I am used to learning on localhost and if something goes wrong I wan't to be able to restore the live site to normal.  I understand I can manually create a backup of the file I am working on every time, but if you have any shortcuts that would be great.  Thanks, Max.

Answer (score 3):

Well the best practice for working on a live server is: Don't do it :-)

Usually one does have a testing environment which is identical to the production environment. If your build is working on the testing environment, you push it to the production systems.

If you really want to work on the live system, you should use git or svn to keep track of all the changes you do to any file. If one of your edits fail, you can use these systems to go back in time and back to a consistent state of your sources. [version control on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)

A complete testing environment first seems like a big effort. But a broken production site might have a serious impact on your business. And if there are some APIs or services which can not be replicated on the testing site, use mocking to simulate those APIs. [mock objects on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)